# Nginx proxy_pass with PHP authentication?

Tags: nginx, php, authentication, reverse-proxy

Hey so what I'm basically hoping to do is set up nginx as a reverse proxy to an internal IIS server which hosts content. The nginx server would have to authenticate users using a PHP/MySQL login system and if they were not authenticated they would be asked to log in. However if they were logged in then their request would be passed to the IIS server. 
Is it possible to use proxy_pass with this setup? I know I can use auth_basic with a htpasswd file, but can I instead send the request to a PHP auth file, or am I better off using curl or readfile() in PHP to achieve the same request? I was just thinking that from a performance point of view that might not be a best practice. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are describing a web-proxy which authenticates users with it's code. Yes, it's possible. But it this setup, you will have to proxy requests programmatically with PHP curl module, not with nginx itself. For nginx this would look just like a normal PHP web-site.

Althoug this system looks overcomplicated. I'd propose you to authenticate users using IIS methods. And use inginx like a simple reverse-proxy, if you still need it.

Comment: as I thought. I cannot get IIS to do the authentication though as it is a server owned and managed by another company and is out of my control. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you pls help explain? how to call "proxy requests programmatically with PHP curl module"